# Eclipse editor stops accepting input

Tags: eclipse

I am using Eclipse for PHP projects. I use the Project Navigator to create a new PHP file. I give it a name and it puts me in the editor with one line that has <?php. All good so far. So, now I enter a line to declare a function, or a class for that matter. I get to where I enter the { to start the function block and eclipse editor stops accepting input. It looks like this:

```
<?php
function sol2($n) {
```

At that point it won't accept input. I can't enter a newline or even backspace. I click around trying different stuff and eventually I get complete control back. It seems if I don't do anything for like a minute I get control back. After I get control back I can create more functions or classes with no delays.

Is there some setting that is causing this initial delay?

Thanks
Chris K

Comment: I know nothing about php mode, but anyone troubleshooting this will want to know the exact version of Eclipse you are using, and if there are any obviously related stacktraces in the Eclipse log file.

Comment: I am using Eclipse 2021-03(4.19.0), which is probably a little old right now.

Comment: Not really.  Now look at the Eclipse log.  Also, what platform is this on? When it's not accepting input, does the cursor change to a different icon?